Effect of ring fields within the plane of the ring. Why is this formula giving values that are far too high?
I am working on the effect of ring fields (e.g. the gravitation force from a planetary debris ring). Unfortunately, the derived formula is obviously incorrect.

The plot from various equations appears above:

The orange line at the bottom represents the flux from a point source, dropping in proportion to the inverse square of the distance.
The green line above the orange line is calculated by assuming that half the mass is on the point of the ring closest to the distant object being acted on by the flux, and the other half is at the origin. This is the sanity check on the effect of the ring. By tearing the source object in two and placing half at the point on the ring closest to the object (r) at a distance (d0) and the other at the origin, it represents an upper boundary that is significantly larger than what the effect of all the source material placed around the ring would be - not only is most of it further away, but as it strays either side of the origin, so part of the flux on one side of the ring (the Y component) is equal and opposite to that of the other side of the ring below the origin.
The blue line is the plot according to the derived formula and the values should be within the region between the point source and sanity check values.

That it doesn't go in the region bound by the other two, suggests the derivation is incorrect, but I cannot see where it went wrong.

Formula
$$
F_{rp} = 
\int_0^\pi 2
\cos\left(
  \arctan\left(
    \frac{r \sin(\theta)}
         {d_0 - r \cos(\theta)}
  \right)
\right)
\frac{K f_1 f_2}
     {(d_0 - r \cos(\theta))^2 + (r \sin(\theta))^2}
\, \mathrm d \theta.
$$
I'm unsure how to include the derivation inline here, or if the reader needs it, but the details are available in RingFieldDebug.nb.
All or any help would be greatly appreciated.
Update:
An attempt to calculate the area of a circle using integration over the angle provided erroneous results. This suggests I do not understand how to use the calculus. (Ugh..)

I'm pretty sure you can assume (by Newton's shell theorem) that the ring is a point mass. As for your actual question, what are $f_1$ and $f_2$?

And what is the $\cos(\tan^{-1}(\cdot))$ term doing? I think that should be a constant value (if the mass is uniformly distributed around the ring).

@VarunVejalla  Yep, a shell of matter behaves exactly like a point mass, but an oblate shell does not - satellite paths in orbit need to account for the oblateness. Further, the formula for the effect of a ring of matter along the axis perpendicular to the ring is well documented (because it's easy to derive). It is less than the effect from a point source at ANY distance. My bad in regards to f1 and f2, I mislabeled them from f0 and f1. Each represents a 'source of flux' that may be gravitation or electric. As to the meaning of the cos/atan structure, it is due to only part ..

@VarunVejalla .. of the flux of the ring acting in a way that does not cancel itself out. Since fp is above the X axis, and has a counterpart at the same distance beneath the axis, the Y component of any effect cancels itself out. Thanks for looking at the problem. Do you use Mathematica? The notebook has extra details.

So to be clear, the rings are ellipses, not circles? And what are $f_0$ and $f_1$?

@VarunVejalla The ring is a perfect circle. To try to clarify the 'f notation'. Imagine we have a 1 gm mass at the point in the diagram marked f0, and 1 gm of mass spread in the (perfectly circular) ring labelled f1. (In the Notebook formulae they are labelled f1 and f2, which makes more sense.)

@VarunVejalla PS: I corrected the notation in the Notebook diagram and changed the graphic. Now the NB should read f1 and f2 consistently and there should be no mention of 'f0' - unless I missed an instance.

Maybe the result is wrong because he value of $\phi$ provided by the function $\operatorname{atan}$ is shifted. Anyway, we have $r\cos\theta+d\cos\phi=d_0$, so $\cos\phi$ can be simplified to $\frac{d_0-r\cos\theta}{d}$. Moreover, $d^2$ can be simplified to $d_0^2+r^2-2d_0r\cos\theta$.

@AlexRavsky I do not understand what "atan is shifted" means. Shifted by, and in relation to, what? Can you expand on that?

The instructions for how to write mathematical derivations on this site start at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation ... I have converted your main formula to this markup as an example.

@DavidK Great! Thanks for the heads-up. I loathe 'images of text' and will bookmark those instructions for future use.

Starting with
$$
F_{rp} = 
\int_0^\pi 2
\cos\left(
  \arctan\left(
    \frac{r \sin(\theta)}
         {d_0 - r \cos(\theta)}
  \right)
\right)
\frac{K f_1 f_2}
     {(d_0 - r \cos(\theta))^2 + (r \sin(\theta))^2}
\, \mathrm d \theta,
$$
note that $\cos(\arctan(x)) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}.$ Therefore
\begin{align}
\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{r\sin(\theta)}{d_0 - r\cos(\theta)}\right)\right)
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\dfrac{r\sin(\theta)}{d_0 - r\cos(\theta)}\right)^2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{(r\sin(\theta))^2 + (d_0 - r\cos(\theta))^2}
                        {(d_0 - r\cos(\theta))^2}}}\\
&= \frac{d_0 - r\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{(r\sin(\theta))^2 + (d_0 - r\cos(\theta))^2}}.
\end{align}
This allows the integral to be written
$$
F_{rp} = 
2 K f_1 f_2
\int_0^\pi
\frac{d_0 - r\cos(\theta)}{((d_0 - r \cos(\theta))^2 + (r \sin(\theta))^2)^{3/2}}
\, \mathrm d \theta.
$$
This is still a difficult integral. I was able to get Wolfram Alpha to evaluate it, but only for literal numeric values of $d_0$ and $r$,
and even then the exact answer involves complete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind.
For $d_0 = 2$ and $r = K = f_1 = f_2 = 1$, I get $F_{rp} \approx 1.95662,$
which agrees with your plot.
As for how to interpret this integral, the quantity
$$
\frac{K f_1 f_2 (d_0 - r\cos(\theta))}
     {((d_0 - r \cos(\theta))^2 + (r \sin(\theta))^2)^{3/2}}
$$
is the amount of gravitational force along the horizontal axis
contributed per unit of ring length at the angle $\theta$ around the ring,
where $K$ is the gravitational constant,
$f_1$ is the total mass of the point mass,
and $f_2$ is the linear density of the ring, that is, the amount of mass per unit of ring length.
(The factor $2$ does not occur here because it represents the fact that $0$ to $\theta$ covers only half the ring, and the other half contributes an equal horizontal force.)
Note that this implies that the total mass of the ring is $2\pi f_2$,
because $f_2$ is the mass per unit length and the complete ring has length $2\pi$.
My guess is that you intended $f_2$ to be the total mass of the ring,
because that makes sense of the plots of the gravitational force for point masses.
If so, the mass per unit length along the ring is $\dfrac{f_2}{2\pi}$,
and you need to divide your integrand by $2\pi$ to get the correct result for the question you intended to ask.
If you make that change to the integral, you get $F_{rp} \approx 0.311405$,
which is comfortably between the green and orange curves on your graph.
The rest of the graph also fits between the curves, as shown below.


Thank you! I will not have a moment to go through your (wonderful) answer till this evening (8 hours or so) but it does appear (by the curves) to be what I was expecting - and very similar to what I had seen when breaking the delta theta into small parts and summing around the ring.

Thanks again. That has got me back on track. BTW - this may one day become part of a published paper. I would like to add a 'Special thanks to..' section to acknowledge your assistance. Would you mind?
